# What happens when you declare two or more classes inside one .java file with the file name same as the public class in it?

Tags: java, class

Does it creates individual .class files when it gets compiled? Is it something right to do?

Comment: That would be easy to try out!

Comment: You can create inner classes and anonymous classes inside of a main public class.  I do it all the time so I can paste [answers in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66210678/swing-window-doesnt-return-value-after-x-time/66212769#66212769) as one block of code.

Comment: Try it and you’ll see multiple.class files resulting after compile. Problem is it’s non-standard, non-idiomatic practice, thus confusing.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc You can even define multiple top-level classes in a single file, but only one of them can be public.

Answer (score 1):

The Java Language Specification ([JLS 7.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6)) states:

> *"It is a compile-time error if the name of a top level type appears as the name of any other top level class or interface type declared in the same package."*

Since all top level type declarations in a file are members of the same package, *it follows* that if you declare two top-level types with the same name in the same file, then the second one is violating the above rule.

The spec also states the following:

> *"If and only if packages are stored in a file system (§7.2), the host system may choose to enforce the restriction that it is a compile-time error if a type is not found in a file under a name composed of the type name plus an extension (such as .java or .jav) if either of the following is true:*
>
> - *The type is referred to by code in other ordinary compilation units of the package in which the type is declared.*
> - *The type is declared public (and therefore is potentially accessible from code in other packages)."*

This means that (for such implementations) only one of the top-level types in a file can be `public`.

(Most Java compilers do enforce this restriction.)

However, if you don't break the restrictions above, the Java language allows you to declare multiple top level types in a single file.

---

> Does it create individual `.class` files when it gets compiled?

Yes.  Indeed, there is also a separate `.class` file generated for any nested or inner classes, and for any lambdas.

---

> Is it something right to do?

It is generally thought to be a bad idea to do this.  Some Java style guides explicitly say there should be one top-level type declaration per source file.  Others are silent on this.

Since multiple types in a single source file are unusual in practice, most programmers don't expect this.  Thus it is a readability concern, which is a practical reason not to do it.